# Can you add content only to the css file and have it not be overwritten whenever you decided to update your sass file with a new content?

Tags: html, css, sass

Every time I add a new style to my CSS file and save then the update shows up on the HTML page, however, if I add a style on my sass scss file and update it via command line, i notice that it updates my CSS file but also deletes whatever style contents i had previously only written to my CSS file. I want to be able to keep both updates...

Comment: That's the whole point of SASS; you update the `scss` files and they get written to the CSS file. You're not *meant* to update the CSS file manually.

Comment: when you compile `.scss`, it will replace your `.css` file. You will need to separate your css from `.scss` output

Comment: *thank you for your clarification .*